# Can't trigger GPIO control via executable run through php's exec function

Tags: gpio, c++, wiringpi

**/var/www/html/index.php**

```
<?php

exec("./on");
shell_exec("/var/www/html/on");
```

**on.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>

using namespace std;

void light_1_on() {
  digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv){

  cout << "Setting up wiringPi" << endl;
  wiringPiSetup();
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT);

  light_1_on();

}
```

Built using: **g++ on.cpp -o on -lwiringPi**

Permissions changed with: **chmod 777 on**

Access changed with: **chown www-data:www-data on**

When run `./on` via the terminal, the light that's connected to this GPIO output turns on. But when run via my exec or shell_exec via php, the light does not turn on.

Any ideas why I might not be able to turn the light on via execution in php? Any fixes or workarounds for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like permissions problem. See [wiringPi non-root access to GPIO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831336/wiringpi-non-root-access-to-gpio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I had to add gpio to the group for www-data. I had to use this:

`sudo usermod -a -G gpio www-data`

Took me quite a while to figure this out. Hope it helps someone!